# Could not find 'passenger' when trying to install passenger-install-nginx-module

Tags: ruby, nginx, rubygems, bundler, passenger

I'm getting the same error every time I'm trying to install the `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'passenger' (>= 0) among 114 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/bin/passenger:22:in `<main>'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

#### Sys. info:

- OSX 10.0.4
- ruby 2.0.0-p247
- rails 4
- passenger 4.0.20 (installed with `rvmsudo`)

#### P.S.

I already used `rvmsudo`, so just using this doesn't solve the problem as some other questions/answers could propose. I think the problem is in paths, but where?

## Update:

I did the same without `rvmsudo` (install the passenger gem), but still running the `(rvmsudo) passenger-install-nginx-module` causes the error with missing gem `passenger`

## Update2:

I installed `homebrew` and with its help installed `passenger`. Then installed passenger nginx module which didn't work:

```
Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/lib/phusion-passenger/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is applicable.
```

Then I installed the passenger nginx module with `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`, so now it worked. I configured it for my rails app. But if I start nginx from `/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx` and navigate to the vhost to my rails application I get:

```
No data received
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

If I look to the `/opt/nginx/log/error.log` I get for that request:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
2013/10/21 15:15:30 [alert] 54636#0: worker process 54723 exited on signal 6
```

What could be here a problem, is it passenger? My rails app worked with WebRick well, and it runs on another server also good with passenger. Maybe it is already another question...

Comment: trying running the install from a different directory than your app.

Comment: already did, no difference. now trying homebrew version

Answer (score 0):

try

```
brew install nginx --with-passenger
```

Comment: didn't work. I installed only passenger with `homebrew`, but then should still install `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`

Comment: try running passenger standalone. cd into your rails project directory and type `passenger start`. That should install and configure nginx and passenger to run in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

Phusion Passenger author here. First of all, I apologize for the problems. We're doing our best to make the installation experience as problem-free as possible.

From the information you've provided, I'm not entirely sure what went wrong. I'd like to go over this with you, so that we automatically check for (and prevent) these kinds of problems in the future. If you have time today, could you join the IRC channel #passenger on irc.freenode.net? My time zone is Europe/Amsterdam.

Comment: thanks for the response! what is your nickname?, I'm already there